# CloudWatch, How to monitor metric only for a specific period time of a day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a use case where I'm expecting some write volume to my Dynamodb table everyday around 3pm from a kinesis stream, the streaming takes about 20 mins.

So in order to make sure the kinesis successfully put data to my Dynamodb table, I want to use CloudWatch to monitor such behavior on my Dynamodb and configure a alarm saying, if everyday around 3pm to 4pm, there's no write traffic to my Dynamodb table, alarm.

Does Cloudwatch support such use case?

1. I have tried to set up an alarm saying I'm expecting write volume to my table on a daily basis, if not, alarm. However, I want to shorten this period since I know if there's no write volume around 3pm, something must be wrong and actions need to be taken. I don't want to wait till the day is over.
2. I know you can use math on metric, but after reading the document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html, I don't think my use case is supported, unless I missed something?

Appreciate any suggestions here! Thanks!

Comment: what about writing some simple Lambda function which would take care of enabling/disabling/setting up the CloudWatch alarm?

Comment: But then I need something to trigger the lambda right?

Comment: you can trigger it at 3pm - to enable the alarm - and at 4pm - to disable it. just define a cron like schedule with CloudWatch events (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Comment: Emmm, interesting, it's an option, thank you!